# Perception of a Chinese to Korean name

Tags: names

I've seen stuff about Chinese to Korean names and so happened to find my personal name as part of a [legal list of hanja for names](https://www.law.go.kr/LSW/lsBylInfoPLinkR.do?lsiSeq=188000).

I was wondering what the personal name 지항 would sound like to a native speaker though.

Rare or really weird? Outdated? Nice sounding? Masculine/feminine/neutral? Other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

항 is a letter that's hardly used in a Korean name so it sounds really unusual and unique, but it isn't weird for a name either. The letter 항 makes the name sound quite masculine. I don't feel the name is outdated probably because of 지 which is being used more than the older generation.

You may check other names at https://korean-name.com/en/. I couldn't find exact references or credible sources the website is based on, but I feel what it provides is correct in general.